# Only Upgrade solution works!

Tags: deployment, solution-package

We are having a weird issue. None of our WSPs (MOSS 2007 and 2010) work first time they are deployed. We noticed that upgrading solution (after deploying) works.

Our WSPs normally replace user controls in layouts folder. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: When you say "work", does this mean you get an error or changed code isn't updating?

Comment: No Error nothing. The resule  via stsadm is "Operation completed successfully" but files wont be replaced. Then we run upgrade immediately and files get updated.

Comment: try deploying the solutiosn using stsadm with the -local parameter. Otherwise the actual deployment is done by the timer job in the background and you will not see any errors (unless you check the ULS logs)

Comment: As wictor say: operation completet successfully refers only to the timer job. In 2010 you can check the status for a given solution in PowerShell using: Get-SPSolution | select DisplayName, LastOperationResult

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem or have any more information you can add to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding "stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs" as your last step in the initial deployment will fix the issue. It will execute the administrator timer jobs immediately.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262783(office.12).aspx